# Acer Aspire One runs Ubuntu 14.04 slow

Tags: 14.04, intel, acer, ubuntu-netbook, aspire-one

I own a Acer Aspire One that has previously run slow on Microsoft 7, then on Microsoft XP.
It now runs Ubuntu 14.04 and it's just as lagging.

I'm currently wondering whether the machine is too old or too damaged to run 2009-up technology ?

Has anyone encountered this? 
Shud I try an earlier version of Ubuntu?

My machine (netbook) has an Intel Atom Dual Core processor and 2GB RAM.

Thanks,

PS> I'm new to Ubuntu, it's the first time I'm using it and want to learn.

Comment: Did you ever get this sped up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a lighter desktop environment like LXDE.
Open the terminal and type the following

> sudo apt-get install lxde

And then logout and choose LXDE Environment from the loginscreen.

Comment: Or you can also try other desktop environments like MATE or GNOME Flashback.

Comment: thank you. I've done as instructed with the following differences:

Comment: What do you mean by differences?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I'm still encountering problems. I did like you said and when re-loging in i found the option LXDE. the trouble with it was that it seemed to be working 2 desktops but only showing one. So I couldn't work on it either, although ubuntu was running just fine with that environment.

Comment: What does two desktops mean? Two desktop environments?